# Does this equivalency return a bool or int?

Tags: c

I would like to write the following function to return whether a queue is empty or not:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool QueueIsEmpty(Queue *pq)
{
    return (pq->items == 0)? true : false;
}
```

Would doing the following shorthand work for this?

```
bool QueueIsEmpty(Queue *pq)
{
    return pq->items == 0;
}
```

In other words, does that return an `int` or a `bool` when doing the equivalency check? And if it returns a `bool` how does the compiler know to cast it to a `bool`, or is a bool just an `int` behind-the-scenes?

When trying it in Compiler Explorer, both seem to just do `mov eax, 0` and produce identical assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/bY59r3.

Comment: The short-hand is exactly the same (and what's generally preferred).

Comment: Your compiler explorer link links to wrong example, btw.

Comment: I am in doubt if your question is about the C standard or implementation of the standard. A comparison returns an `int`, but compilers are allowed to do anything behind the scenes as long as they get the right result. The practical difference between `bool` and `int` is that `bool` is restricted to two values such that "true" is represented by a unique value while `int` can represent "true" as any non-zero number. Consider the difference in this example where the function returning `bool` needs to ensure the result is 0 or 1: https://godbolt.org/z/YTfPjT.

Comment: @nielsen The standard requires that `==` evaluate to only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

Both are equivalent.

`bool` is considered an integer type which can only hold the values 0 and 1.  `true` has a value of 1 while `false` has a value of 0.

The expression `pq->items == 0` has type `int` and will evaluate to either 0 or 1.  These are both valid values for `bool` so the value will be properly converted.

Comment: nit, technically, `true` has the value of `!false` as any non-zero value will evaluate as `true` (but for practical explanation purposes, `1/0` is a good way to go).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Statements or operators that work on boolean values treat 0 as false and non-zero as true, however 7.18p3 of the standard states that the macro `true` is defined as 1.

Comment: Yes, that is somewhat the opposite side of the same coin. While if you output the expanded value of the macro `true` it will evaluate as `1`, at the same time any non-zero value with also evaluate as `true`.

Comment: " These are both valid values for bool so the value will be properly converted." This is right, but additionally this is *still vague* in wording. Especially there are *no* values of `int` that wouldn't be properly converted to a bool, but the value would not be retained except for 0 and 1...

Answer (score 2):

The value of comparison expression using any of `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `=>` will be a value `1` or `0` for *true* and *false* respectively, and, due to history, will be of type `int`.

`_Bool` type (for which `bool` is a macro alias defined in `<stdbool.h>`) can only store values `1` and `0`. **Additionally**, when converting to `_Bool`, *any nonzero* value will be converted to **1**. [C11 6.3.1.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.2):

> 1. When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is `0` if the value compares equal to `0`; otherwise, the result is `1`. [59]
>
> [59] NaNs do not compare equal to `0` and thus convert to `1`.

Therefore the following is valid:

```
bool QueueIsEmpty(Queue *pq)
{
    return pq->items == 0;
}
```

The `!x` unary operator is exactly equivalent to `x == 0` semantically and syntactically in all contexts, and therefore the former can be substituted everywhere in place of the latter, therefore the following is valid as well:

```
bool QueueIsEmpty(Queue *pq)
{
    return !pq->items;
}
```

and the following is *also* valid for a function with opposite semantics:

```
bool QueueHasItems(Queue *pq)
{
    return pq->items;
}
```

All of the functions have the same semantics regardless of the type of `pq->items` provided that the value of this expression has a scalar type (i.e. boolean, integer, pointer, real or complex floating point), or decays to one (i.e. if `items` is an array, then it will always be true...); and if it is not a scalar type then the code should fail to compile...

This [compiles on x86-64 to](https://godbolt.org/z/sr3ohd)

```
QueueHasItems:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        setne   al
        ret
```

i.e. `al` is set as the result of zero/equality flag after `cmp pq->items, 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`pq->items == 0` results in an `int` with the value of 0 or 1.

`bool QueueIsEmpty()` returns a `bool`  with the value of 0 or 1.  With `stdbool.h`, a `bool` can only have the value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score -1):

In C, there is no true bool type<sup>1</sup>. C uses the concept of falsey and truthy; if the expression evaluates to something non-zero, it can be used as truthy, otherwise, it is falsey.

Therefore in both cases you have, they will have the same effect.

You could also use the `!` operator and do `!pq->items;`, which according to the [logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) documentation is the same as doing `pq->items == 0`

<sup>1</sup> *Since C99, C now supports boolean arithmetic using the [_Bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/_Bool) type, and if you include [`stdbool.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean), you can even get access to the macros **true** or **false**, which expand to `1` or `0`, respectively.*